# How do I install PDFTK on VPS for cPanel or CentOS?

Tags: linux, shell, cpanel, vps, pdftk

I tried using the following commands. However when I reach the last step to install `pdftk` the console is giving me the error below. I am using a hostgator VPS server. any possible suggestions would be great.

NB: I tried installing `libgcj.so.7rh()(64bit)` but it already exists. maybe I am doing something wrong.

```
**Error:** Package: pdftk-1.44-2.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libgcj.so.7rh()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

**These are the steps that I followed.**

```
# Log in as root

cd /usr/local/src

# Type
uname -i 

#To see which package you need
#Pick one of the below vdepending on the output of uname -i

i386<br>
wegt packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm 

x86_64 <br>
wget packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm 

#Then type
rpm --import apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt

Verify the downloaded package
rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm

#Install RPM
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm

#Then
yum install pdftk
```

Note: I had to remove the http:// from the links in the commands above before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have a 32-bit OS installed?  If you ran through each of those commands in order, you would be trying to use the 64-bit rpmforge repository, which is incorrect for a 32-bit OS.

If that is an accurate supposition, do this..

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
ls -al
rm <each-rpmforge-file>
```

Then...

```
cd /usr/local/src
yum clean
wget packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
yum update
yum install pdftk
```